# How to customize json output from controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller that returns a list of categories and a count of items in each category

```
Category.joins(:item).group([:category_id,:name]).count
```

I would like to clean up the json formatting from this

(which is category_id, :name, :count )

```
{"[10, \"Fruit.\"]":2,"[11, \"Vegetables.\"]":1,"[2, \"Pasty.\"]":1}
```

to this

```
{"categoryitemcount":[ {"id":10,"name":"Fruit","count":7}]}
```

so a custom root name along with named columns

thanks in advance!

Comment: Fixed this by making a table less model (Railscast #219)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is demoed in Railscast #219. Basically create a model not backed by a database and which represents the data you want to send back. In my case CategoryItemCount.rb (id, name, count). I built an array of these on the fly using the query given above, and output as json.